# Store java.util.Date as key in a Map based on reference equality instead of "value" equality

Tags: java, date, dictionary, collections

I want to build a HashMap of Date objects so whenever I have two different Date objects of the same Date value (day,month,year, .. ) the Hashmap doesn't replace the past value with the new one.

Example:

```
    Date x = new Date();
    Date y = new Date();

    HashMap<Date,Integer> hm = new HashMap<Date,Integer>();
    hm.put(x,1);
    hm.put(y,3);

    System.out.println(hm.get(x));
    System.out.println(hm.get(y));
```

In this example they both print 3. I want to ensure that they print 1 then 3.

I've thought about putting the key value in Hashmap as the object reference of each date (since they will be different) so how do I enforce the object to do that?

Or is there a better way to do that ?

Comment: Please, read your question and try to rewrite it again. I cannot understand what you want

Comment: what value would your `HashMap` have? And how do you treat these as two unique objects?

Comment: Are you looking for a map that allows duplicate keys?

Comment: Does a `HashMap<Date, X>` not work as expected? Date.hashCode and equals should be well defined. You can dump the map's `entrySet()`.

Comment: Both Date object will generate same date and x and y will be same .

Comment: Sorry, I rewrote the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [java.util.IdentityHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) for this task. That way you can have `equals`, but different objects in your `Map`.

EDIT:
Your example:

```
Date x = new Date();
Date y = new Date();

Map<Date,Integer> hm = new IndentityHashMap<Date,Integer>();
hm.put(x,1);
hm.put(y,3);
assert hm.size() == 2: hm.size();
```

As @BoristheSpider pointed out this might not be the best data structure when you loose the references for the original objects. In that case a `MultiMap` (like [guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)'s) or a `List` of `Entry`s/`Pair`s/`Tuple`s might be a better choice depending on the use case. (The former is for cases when you want all values belonging to certain `equals` keys, the latter is to visit all key/value pairs, but not searching by keys.)

If you just want to use the `Map` as an "array" with random access for certain or all (stored) keys the `IdentityHashMap` is a good choice though.

Comment: @AerRayes note that you can **never** retrieve an `Object` from an `IdentityHashMap` if you lose the original reference.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I think you can loop through the `entrySet()`/`keySet()` of it and regain the original references.

Comment: @GáborBakos only if you somehow find out _what_ you want to regain. How do you check which is the original reference without something to compare that reference to?

Comment: @GáborBakos that I know. But look at the OPs example - the issue is that both `Date` objects _are_ `.equals` which is exactly _why_ an `HashMap` doesn't work. So, if your comment holds any merit, then the `IdentityHashMap` is the wrong construct.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution is to use a unique timestamp.  This will ensure you can retrieve the value by having the same timestamp.

```
private static final AtomicLong MILLIS = new AtomicLong();

public static Date newDate() {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(;;) {
        long prev = MILLIS.get();
        if (prev >= now)
            now = prev + 1;
        if (MILLIS.comapreAndSet(prev, now))
            return new Date(now);
    }
}
```

If you use this Date factory, each data will be unique and as close the the actual time as possible.

```
Date x = newDate();
Date y = newDate();

Map<Date,Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
hm.put(x,1);
hm.put(y,3);

System.out.println(hm.get(x));
System.out.println(hm.get(y));
```

Comment: Or use and `Instant` class from Java 8 (if possible) - it has nano precision so should provide uniqueness.

Comment: @BoristheSpider should but might not on systems with microsecond resolution.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I would assume not just new `Date`s should be stored. It would be quite hard to efficiently and properly adjust the dates to store in a highly concurrent scenario. And it modifies the date too. Do you think this would be a sensible alternative? You could not even get out the values even if you had a reference for the original `Date`s. Maybe I misunderstood your suggestion.

Comment: @GáborBakos I think is is a good alternative which is why I suggested it. It stores as much as it needs to and is highly concurrent although having more than 1000 Dates per second would be a problem. You could use these as keys if you used the original `Date` objects which is why I claimed that the code sample I provided would work.